# Check/Uncheck inputs depending on parent/child input status

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I need to check/uncheck parent and children inputs in order to be logical:

```
[x] parent [ ] child1 [x] child2
```

In this example, if I uncheck `child2`, `parent` needs to be unchecked too. And, if I uncheck `parent`, `child2` can no longer be checked.

```
[ ] parent [ ] child1 [ ] child2
```

In this case, if I check `child2`, `parent` must be checked as well.

I think this is quite logical, a child cannot be checked without its parent being checked, and if I uncheck a child (and this was the only one of the children checked), the parent must be unchecked too.

I'm working on PHP, so any kind of integration with Javascript (jQuery) would be fine for me.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Without your html you can't really answer this question.

Comment: HTML is irrelevant here... Imagine just 3 inputs, one with `class="parent"`, the other two with `class="children"`

Comment: @scumah - it makes a huge difference in terms of your jQuery selectors. Are you going to use .parent(), .find()? Something else?

Comment: @mrtsherman, sure it makes difference, but, in my opinion, the important thing here is the logic and just the logic, not wich selectors are we going to use to find the inputs.

Comment: I think the HTML still makes a big difference. We don't know if he has nested lists. sure we can code something in that solves what we assume the problem is, but I'd rather see html that definitively shows the problem being presented. It's also good practice for people posting questions.

Comment: You are right, I should have pasted the HTML. Apologies, this was my first Stack Overflow question. Anyway, I assumed the HTML would make no difference, which I see, given the answers above, is not 100% true. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, I don't know if I have to open a new question, but I found that my project needs to have more than 1 level of childs, that is, parent, child and grandson, up to 7 o 8 levels.

So, the solution posted below, that fits perfectly the my first request, isn't able to handle more than 1 level of child. Do you know what I should modify? I think that the point of callin "parent" the parent input and "child" the other ones is no longer useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a good starting point:

```
<form id="theform">
    <label>Parent</label><input name="group1" type="checkbox" value="parent1" class="parent" />
    <label>Child 1</label><input name="group1" type="checkbox" value="child1" class="child" />
    <label>Child 2</label><input name="group1" type="checkbox" value="child2" class="child" />
    <label>Child 3</label><input name="group1" type="checkbox" value="child3" class="child" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#theform input:checkbox').change(function(){
            // Parent Checkbox Change //
            if ($(this).hasClass('parent')){
                if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
                    $('input.child[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').removeAttr('checked');
                }
            }
            // Child Checkbox Change //
            else if ($(this).hasClass('child')){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $('input.parent[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                } else {
                    if ($('input.child[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]:checked').length == 0){
                        $('input.parent[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').removeAttr('checked');
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjZnZ/3/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Edited to only un-check parent when all child inputs are un-checked.

Comment: Thank you very much!! both codes work, but I'm choosing dSquared solution because a child checks parent input instead of disallowing it to be checked, which I found is gonna be useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WvYgB/1/

jQuery:

```
$('.parent').change(function(){
    if (!($(this).is(':checked'))) {
        $('.children').attr('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.children').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') && !$('.parent').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
    if (!($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).siblings('.children').is(':checked'))) {
        $('.parent').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: little bug - you can't check a child until the parent has been checked. This is in his spec.

Comment: @mrtsherman, In wich browser are you looking the fiddle? It works for me :(

Comment: Chrome 15, IE9 and FF8. The problem is your first if statement. It says, if this is checked && parent is not checked, then remove the check. It should be checking its parent, not unchecking itself.

Comment: One more thing, your use of `attr` in this case is incorrect. You should be using `prop` with jQuery 1.7 or using attr differently. attr has values of 'checked' or ''. Not true or false. Prop has values of true and false. http://jsfiddle.net/fGdAY/

Comment: You are right, but using `prop('checked')` or `attr('checked')` wont work, as inputs might not have the `checked` property, and this messes things up a bit. Check [jQuery's prop() page](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), the demo shows us an input like this: `<input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">`, that's incorrect, but it doesn't seems to work. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WvYgB/2/ . And about the little bug you noticed,  I understood that if the parent wasn't checked, you can't check a children, not that the parent should be checked too: http://jsfiddle.net/WvYgB/3/

Comment: Ahh, I see exactly what you are saying now. Makes sense. Good job.